# Image Processing - Nearest interpolation algorithm perform weird

Tags: c++, image-processing

I am doing the nearest interpolation algorithm to scale a .rgb format image in c++. The original resolution of the image is 352x288. My implementation of the algorithm is weird. When I scaled it to half of its original size or enlarge it to 2 times of the original one, it works pretty good. However, when I want to scale it to some other factors like 0.8 or 1.2, the display is abnormal.

Here is my piece of code:

```
void MyImage::Sampling(int destWidth, int destHeight){
//Use nearest sampling
char* temp = new char[destWidth * destHeight * 3];

double scale_w = Width / (double)destWidth;
double scale_h = Height / (double)destHeight;

int tSrcH = 0, tSrcW = 0;
int index_src = 0, index_dest = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < destHeight; ++i){
    //Find the nearest y_pos in the original image 
    tSrcH = (int)(scale_h * i + 0.5); 
    for(int j = 0; j < destWidth; ++j){
        //Find the nearest y_pos in the original image 
        tSrcW = (int)(scale_w * j + 0.5);

        //Get the data in the original image
        //and assign it to the new image
        index_src = getIndex(tSrcW, tSrcH, Width);
        index_dest = getIndex(j, i, destWidth);

        //B, G, R
        temp[3 * index_dest]     = Data[3 * index_src];
        temp[3 * index_dest + 1] = Data[3 * index_src + 1];
        temp[3 * index_dest + 2] = Data[3 * index_src + 2];
    }
}

Width = destWidth;
Height = destHeight;

delete [] Data; 
Data = NULL;

Data = new char[destWidth * destHeight * 3];

for(int i = 0; i < destWidth * destHeight * 3; ++i){
    Data[i] = temp[i];
}

delete [] temp;
}
```

**The Original Image**

[image]

**The Half-sized Image**

[image]

**0.8 Scaled Image**

[image]

Any suggestion or solution to this situation? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a direct solution either. Are you sure your input is okay and e.g. not a real-time / volatile buffer being updated during that operation or s.th.? Also, ensure `getIndex(j,i,w)` really honors the given w and does not revert to the member `Width` or expect swapped j and i (i would have done it the other way round). Finally, your copy operation at the end seems useless, just `delete[] Data;` and `Data = temp;`.

Comment: @Thomas Hi, thanks for your reply, I have tried to debug it for the whole day but I hardly could see any wrong coding. I did a lot of experiments with different input width and height value. I have found that some width value could generate the scale image properly no matter what height value is and others could not. But I still don't know what is the cause of such weird problem.

Comment: @Thomas I see a kind of pattern, when width could be divided by 4, then the image is ok...

Comment: @Zengrui, I have used `int getIndex(int w,int h,int stride){return h*stride+w;}` and used almost your same code+opencv to visualize the image. Your code is working fine. I guess the problem might be somewhere else, like maybe your visualization code. Most likely the cause might be related to integer sizes used to represent pixels being mismatched somewhere.

Comment: @ZawLin thanks for your reply. I will try to figure out what's going on with the integer representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @ZawLin and i found that the widths of your posted images do not add up.

The original is 353 (not 352 as you stated) and more interesting the 0.8x scaled is 285 wide instead of 352*0.8=282. 
So i guess you sample three extra pixels (285-282) from the 1st line during rendering the 0th line and add them at the end of your 0th line. This for the next line its already 6, then 9 and so on. Thus the image looks tilted.

So i conclude you render the scaled 282 wide image to a 285 wide area.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, please note the picture I posted here is a screen-shot, not the original picture, but your point is helpful, I will continue to look into it.